# KMP pattern find algorithm

Tags: algorithm, string-matching

I did understand the KMP algorithm, i.e the concept of storing value for matching suffix with prefix and then not going back when searching in a string, as for a pattern "abcdabca" prefix array will be {0,0,0,0,1,2,3,1} 
I understand till {0,0,0,0,1,2,3,_} and then 'd' at 4th position doesn't match with 'a' at last. And then the algo says to go back to arr[j-1] if j!=0, I can see that this gives us the right result but I can't understand why are we going back to previous element[data] for a understanding basis.

We go back till we find a matching element or j==0, I can't figure a way to understand why are we going back.

Thanks

Comment: Understanding going back on mismatch is not a simple matter. Try the example and some more examples, by hand on a paper to figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my own understanding, we use failure function `F[i]` to represent to 0-based index of the longest prefix which is the same as suffix of the sub-string `S[0...i]` (for longest, I mean the longest other than the whole sub-string itself)

From your OP, I think your implementation or tutorial is using 1-based but that's totally depends on implementation

Consider the following example: `S = abababcabab`

The Failure Function would be like `F = [-1,-1,0,1,2,3,-1,0,1,2,3]`

What you may look carefully is what's happening when the algorithm is at the time of finish calculating Failure Function for `S' = ababab????` and `F = [-1,-1,0,1,2,3,?,?,?,?,?]`

Now the next character is `c`, the algorithm will test if it can append on the already known longest prefix (suffix) `abab` to make a longer one. The test fails as prefix `ababa` != suffix `ababc`, but what then?

Then the algorithm will try to look the **longest prefix (suffix) of the failed longest prefix (suffix)** and see what about pending a `c` on that will give us a match (if yes, then it is the answer).

This means the algorithm will test the **longest prefix (suffix) of** `abab` which is `ab`, and we can know that quickly because we know `F(abab) = 3` (which we test to append a `c` and fails) and we know `F(F(abab)) = F(3) = 1`, which is the position of `ab`.

The same thing happens recursively, until as you said we find a match or there is no match at all. The "jumping" of the `F[]` when matches fail is implementing this process: Test the next potential longest prefix (suffix), if fail, find the next one...